# goJS custom behaviour for nodes

Tags: javascript, python, gojs

I have simple python flask app where I send JSON data to my HTML and with goJS I display my graph which looks like this:

[image]

I want to make this bevahiour for my graph but I dont know if thats possible since you have to strictly set graph edit mode. What I want is this:

1. I load data model where some nodes and links will have standard text (eg. "node1" or "link1") and others will have "?"
2. Both nodes and links with "?" and standard text can be deleted
3. Users can NOT add new nodes and links
4. Nodes and links with text "?" can be renamed
5. Nodes and links with standard text CAN NOT be renamed

Is this possible to implement or not ?

Here is my code and what I tried so far (this is python flask app) and data model is loaded from JSON sent from flask action:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>State Chart</title>
<meta name="description" content="A finite state machine chart with editable and interactive features." />
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gojs/1.7.27/go.js"></script>
<script src="https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/TextEditorRadioButtons.js"></script>
<script src="https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/TextEditorSelectBox.js"></script>
<script src="https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/DataInspector.js"></script>
<link href="https://gojs.net/latest/extensions/DataInspector.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script id="code">

    function init() {

        var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
        myDiagram =
        $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",  // must name or refer to the DIV HTML element
        {
            // start everything in the middle of the viewport
            initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
            // have mouse wheel events zoom in and out instead of scroll up and down
            "toolManager.mouseWheelBehavior": go.ToolManager.WheelZoom,
            // support double-click in background creating a new node
            "clickCreatingTool.archetypeNodeData": { text: "new node" },
            // enable undo & redo
            "undoManager.isEnabled": true,
            "layout": new go.ForceDirectedLayout()
        });


        // when the document is modified, add a "*" to the title and enable the "Save" button
        myDiagram.addDiagramListener("Modified", function(e) {
            var button = document.getElementById("SaveButton");
            if (button) button.disabled = !myDiagram.isModified;
            var idx = document.title.indexOf("*");
            if (myDiagram.isModified) {
            if (idx < 0) document.title += "*";
            } else {
            if (idx >= 0) document.title = document.title.substr(0, idx);
            }
        });

            // define the Node template
        myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
          $(go.Node, "Auto",
            new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
            // define the node's outer shape, which will surround the TextBlock
            $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle",
              {
                parameter1: 20,  // the corner has a large radius
                fill: $(go.Brush, "Linear", { 0: "rgb(254, 201, 0)", 1: "rgb(254, 162, 0)" }),
                stroke: null,
                portId: "",  // this Shape is the Node's port, not the whole Node
                fromLinkable: true, fromLinkableDuplicates: true,
                toLinkable: true, toLinkableDuplicates: true,
                cursor: "pointer"
              }),
            $(go.TextBlock,
              {
                font: "bold 11pt helvetica, bold arial, sans-serif",
                editable: true  // editing the text automatically updates the model data
                //textEditor: window.TextEditorRadioButtons, // defined in textEditorRadioButtons.js
                // this specific TextBlock has its own choices:
              },
            new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
        );

        myDiagram.nodeTemplate.selectionAdornmentTemplate =
        $(go.Adornment, "Spot",
            $(go.Panel, "Auto",
            $(go.Shape, { stroke: "dodgerblue", strokeWidth: 2, fill: null }),
            $(go.Placeholder)
        ),
        $(go.Panel, "Horizontal",
            { alignment: go.Spot.Top, alignmentFocus: go.Spot.Bottom },
            $("Button",
                { click: editText },  // defined below, to support editing the text of the node
                $(go.TextBlock, "t",
                { font: "bold 10pt sans-serif", desiredSize: new go.Size(15, 15), textAlign: "center" })
            ),
            $("Button",
            { // drawLink is defined below, to support interactively drawing new links
                click: drawLink,  // click on Button and then click on target node
                actionMove: drawLink  // drag from Button to the target node
            },
            $(go.Shape,
                { geometryString: "M0 0 L8 0 8 12 14 12 M12 10 L14 12 12 14" })
            ),
            $("Button",
            {
                actionMove: dragNewNode,  // defined below, to support dragging from the button
                _dragData: { text: "?????", color: "lightgray" },  // node data to copy
                click: clickNewNode  // defined below, to support a click on the button
            },
            $(go.Shape,
                { geometryString: "M0 0 L3 0 3 10 6 10 x F1 M6 6 L14 6 14 14 6 14z", fill: "gray" })
          )
        )
      );

    function editText(e, button) {
        //console.log(e);

      var node = button.part.adornedPart;
      console.log("node");
      //console.log(node);
      e.diagram.commandHandler.editTextBlock(node.findObject("TEXTBLOCK"));
      //$("#nodeText").val(node.findObject("TEXTBLOCK"));
    }

    function drawLink(e, button) {
      var node = button.part.adornedPart;
      var tool = e.diagram.toolManager.linkingTool;
      tool.startObject = node.port;
      e.diagram.currentTool = tool;
      tool.doActivate();
    }

   // used by both clickNewNode and dragNewNode to create a node and a link
    // from a given node to the new node
    function createNodeAndLink(data, fromnode) {
        var diagram = fromnode.diagram;
        var model = diagram.model;
        var nodedata = model.copyNodeData(data);
        model.addNodeData(nodedata);
        var newnode = diagram.findNodeForData(nodedata);
        var linkdata = model.copyLinkData({});
        model.setFromKeyForLinkData(linkdata, model.getKeyForNodeData(fromnode.data));
        model.setToKeyForLinkData(linkdata, model.getKeyForNodeData(newnode.data));
        model.addLinkData(linkdata);
        diagram.select(newnode);
        return newnode;
    }

    // the Button.click event handler, called when the user clicks the "N" button
    function clickNewNode(e, button) {
        var data = button._dragData;
        if (!data) return;
        e.diagram.startTransaction("Create Node and Link");
        var fromnode = button.part.adornedPart;
        var newnode = createNodeAndLink(button._dragData, fromnode);
        newnode.location = new go.Point(fromnode.location.x + 200, fromnode.location.y);
        e.diagram.commitTransaction("Create Node and Link");
    }

    // the Button.actionMove event handler, called when the user drags within the "N" button
    function dragNewNode(e, button) {
        var tool = e.diagram.toolManager.draggingTool;
        if (tool.isBeyondDragSize()) {
            var data = button._dragData;
            if (!data) return;
            e.diagram.startTransaction("button drag");  // see doDeactivate, below
            var newnode = createNodeAndLink(data, button.part.adornedPart);
            newnode.location = e.diagram.lastInput.documentPoint;
            // don't commitTransaction here, but in tool.doDeactivate, after drag operation finished
            // set tool.currentPart to a selected movable Part and then activate the DraggingTool
            tool.currentPart = newnode;
            e.diagram.currentTool = tool;
            tool.doActivate();
        }
    }

    // using dragNewNode also requires modifying the standard DraggingTool so that it
    // only calls commitTransaction when dragNewNode started a "button drag" transaction;
    // do this by overriding DraggingTool.doDeactivate:
    var tool = myDiagram.toolManager.draggingTool;
    tool.doDeactivate = function() {
        // commit "button drag" transaction, if it is ongoing; see dragNewNode, above
        if (tool.diagram.undoManager.nestedTransactionNames.elt(0) === "button drag") {
            tool.diagram.commitTransaction();
        }
        go.DraggingTool.prototype.doDeactivate.call(tool);  // call the base method
    };

    // replace the default Link template in the linkTemplateMap
    myDiagram.linkTemplate =
        $(go.Link,  // the whole link panel
        {
            curve: go.Link.Bezier, 
            adjusting: go.Link.Stretch,
            reshapable: true, 
            relinkableFrom: true, 
            relinkableTo: true,
            toShortLength: 3
        },
        new go.Binding("points").makeTwoWay(),
        new go.Binding("curviness"),
        $(go.Shape,  // the link shape
            { strokeWidth: 1.5 }),
        $(go.Shape,  // the arrowhead
            { toArrow: "standard", stroke: null }),
        $(go.Panel, "Auto",
            $(go.Shape,  // the label background, which becomes transparent around the edges
            {
                fill: $(go.Brush, "Radial",
                      { 0: "rgb(240, 240, 240)", 0.3: "rgb(240, 240, 240)", 1: "rgba(240, 240, 240, 0)" }),
                stroke: null
            }),
            $(go.TextBlock, "?????",  // the label text
            {

                textAlign: "center",
                font: "9pt helvetica, arial, sans-serif",
                margin: 4,
                editable: true  // enable in-place editing
            },
            // editing the text automatically updates the model data
            new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
        )
    );


    var inspector = new Inspector('myInspectorDiv', myDiagram,
    {
        // uncomment this line to only inspect the named properties below instead of all properties on each object:
        // includesOwnProperties: false,
        properties: {
            "text": { },
            // an example of specifying the type
            //"password": { show: Inspector.showIfPresent, type: 'password' },
            // key would be automatically added for nodes, but we want to declare it read-only also:
            //"key": { readOnly: true, show: Inspector.showIfPresent },
            // color would be automatically added for nodes, but we want to declare it a color also:
            //"color": { show: Inspector.showIfPresent, type: 'color' },
            // Comments and LinkComments are not in any node or link data (yet), so we add them here:
            //"Comments": { show: Inspector.showIfNode  },
            //"flag": { show: Inspector.showIfNode, type: 'checkbox' },
            //"LinkComments": { show: Inspector.showIfLink },
            //"isGroup": { readOnly: true, show: Inspector.showIfPresent }
        }
    });

    // read in the JSON data from flask
    loadGraphData();

    }

    function loadGraphData() {
        var graphDataString = JSON.parse('{{ diagramData | tojson | safe}}');
        console.log("graphDataString");
        console.log(graphDataString);

        myDiagram.model = go.Model.fromJson(graphDataString);
    }

    function saveGraphData(form, event) {
        console.log("inside saveGraphData");
        event.preventDefault();

        document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value = myDiagram.model.toJson();
        form.submit();
    }

    function zoomToFit(){
        console.log("inside zoomToFit");
        myDiagram.zoomToFit();
    }

    function zoomIn(){
        console.log("inside zoomIn");
        myDiagram.commandHandler.increaseZoom();
    }

    function zoomOut(){
        console.log("inside zoomOut");
        myDiagram.commandHandler.decreaseZoom();
    }

    function simulateUndo(){
        console.log("simulateUndo");
        myDiagram.commandHandler.undo();

    }

    function simulateRedo(){
        console.log("simulateRedo");
        myDiagram.commandHandler.redo();
    }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <div id=formWrapper style="padding: 30px;">

        <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:5000/updateResultFile" name="updateResultFileForm" 
        id="updateResultFileForm" 
        onsubmit="saveGraphData(this, event);">

            <div id="graphWrapper" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="border: solid 1px black; width: 100%; height: 800px;margin-bottom: 15px;"></div>
                <div style="display: none;"><input id="mySavedModel" name="mySavedModel"></div>

                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"> Save <i class="fa fa-save"> </i> </button>

            </div>

        </form>

        <div id="myInspectorDiv">
        </div>

        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="zoomToFit()"> Zoom to fit  <i class="fa fa-search"> </i> </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="zoomIn()"> Zoom in  <i class="fa fa-search-plus"> </i> </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="zoomOut()"> Zoom out  <i class="fa fa-search-minus"> </i> </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="simulateUndo()"> Undo <i class="fa fa-undo"> </i> </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="simulateRedo()"> Redo <i class="fa fa-redo"> </i> </button>
        </div>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a **Binding** to your **Node** and **Link** templates:

    `new go.Binding("deletable", "text", function(t) { return t === "?"; }),`

Add a **Binding** to your **TextBlock**s:

    `new go.Binding("editable", "text", function(t) { return t === "?"; }),`

Set **Diagram.allowInsert** to false.  Setting **Diagram.allowCopy** to false might be sufficient too -- I'm not sure exactly what situations you want to prevent the user from doing.  Read more at https://gojs.net/latest/intro/permissions.html.

Comment: Thank you, Walter! I managed to set it all to work properly, just one more thing, if user changes text from "?" to something different then text can not be edited again. Maybe I wrote it in question a bit confusing, but I want that nodes with STARTING text "?" can be editable.
I added "fe" (flagEditable) attribute to nodes and links in my data model to all nodes and links, and nodes with "?" starting text have "fe" attribute set to true, and others to false. Is there any way I can check that attribute in binding functions you wrote in your answer ?

Comment: Sure, just make the binding conversion function smarter.